# Use EXISTS in a JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, exists, not-exists

I'm fresh out of school and have just started to using Oracle SQL developer at work. My goal in this particular query is to obtain account numbers that have gone dormant or inactive. The problem I came across is that some of these accounts have active loans and so I want to exclude those specific accounts from the results. I'm trying to use the Exists clause to accomplish this, but the results will still include these accounts. This is the Join I'm using:

```
LEFT JOIN ACCTLOAN ALN ON ACCT.ACCTNBR = ALN.ACCTNBR AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ALN.ACCTNBR FROM ACCT
          WHERE ALN.ACCTNBR = ACCT.ACCTNBR)
```

The query has two other inner joins before it and other conditions below it. Everything works except the Exists clause.

Comment: How does it "not work"?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the "anti-join" pattern to find records that don't have a corresponding record in another table.

In your case:

```
LEFT JOIN ACCTLOAN ALN ON ACCT.ACCTNBR = ALN.ACCTNBR AND ALN.ACCTNBR IS NULL
```

Please note that since you are doing a left join, `ALN.ACCTNBR` will be `NULL` for all accounts that don't have any matching record in `ALN`.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting from the wrong (outer) ACCT rangetable entry. Adding aliases to **all** your table references will fix this:

```
...
FROM ACCT A
LEFT JOIN ACCTLOAN ALN ON A.ACCTNBR = ALN.ACCTNBR 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM ACCT X
          WHERE ALN.ACCTNBR = X.ACCTNBR
    );
```

This still makes no sense. Maybe you just want the *plain* `NOT EXISTS()` ?

```
 ...
FROM ACCT A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM ACCTLOAN X
    WHERE X.ACCTNBR = A.ACCTNBR
    );
```